# Matplotlib issue in Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been using Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda in Windows (Pyhton 3.7). However, as I have been using the cvxpy package and some higher dimensional operation can't be done on Python 3.7, I installed Python 3.6Test notebook on Jupyter. This solved the issue with higher dimensional matrices. Now I am having issues with importing matplotlib. The error message says "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'**", whereas the package is clearly installed in the base environment. [Error Message attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJTba.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: Is ur Python3.6 present in the same base environment as where the matplotlib is installed?

Comment: _the package is clearly installed in the base environment._ Using the base environment for all your projects defeats the purpose of virtual environments. Where did you install the other packages? Can you share the output of `conda list` for each relevant env?

Comment: Nope. Python 3.6 is not present in the base environment. How do I do that?

Comment: AMC, For the time being, I have downgraded to Python 3.6 and that seems to work. However, I definitely want to use the most recent version

Comment: @user171766 I didn't say anything about which version of Python you use, I said you should stay away from the base environment (my opinion hasn't changed). Every "fix" you make which involves installing/removing packages from the base env, as you appear to have done, can only complicate things further.